Discord.py cog gets duplicated
I am trying to set up a daily report with discord.py. You can find my (minimised) code below. The idea is to retain the reports through bot restarts by using a database to reinitialise them during on_ready. The problem is that sometimes two identical cogs seem to get added and the DO SOMETHING part runs twice (or more). This gets fixed by manually removing the cog (via name) from both active_cogs and the database and readding it. But I cannot understand why and how it gets duplicated – I thought two cogs cannot have the same cog_name, hence why I am identifying the cog with the id and time of the report.
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

active_cogs: list[commands.Cog] = []

class Reporter(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, cur_bot: commands.Bot, author_id, time_string):
        self.__cog_name__ = f"{author_id}:{time_string}"
        self.bot = cur_bot
        self.time_of_report = time(hour=self.time, minute=0, second=0)
        self.reportee = None
        asyncio.create_task(self.init_reportee(author_id))

        self.reporter.start()

    async def init_reportee(self, author_id):
        self.reportee = await self.bot.fetch_user(author_id)
        self.reporter.change_interval(time=self.time_of_report)

    @tasks.loop()
    async def reporter(self):
        # DO SOMETHING

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    active_reports = get_all_reports() # this gets requested reports from db
    for report in active_reports:
        report_cog = Reporter(cur_bot=bot, author_id=report[0], time_string=report[1])
        active_cogs.append(report_cog)
        await bot.add_cog(report_cog)

@bot.hybrid_command(name='addreport')
async def addreport(ctx, hour: int):
    add_report_to_db(ctx.author.id, date_and_time, mode)
    new_reporter = Reporter(cur_bot=bot, author_id=ctx.author.id, time_string=hour)
    active_cogs.append(new_reporter)
    await bot.add_cog(new_reporter)



Do not add cogs in on_ready this function is not guaranteed to only be called once.

It is better to load cogs by overwriting the default bot.setup_hook function inherited by commands.Bot. You would do this by creating your own bot class which inherits commands.Bot as so:
class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    async def setup_hook(self):
    # use this to add the cogs to the bot
        active_reports = get_all_reports() # this gets requested reports from db
        for report in active_reports:
            report_cog = Reporter(
                cur_bot = self, 
                author_id = report[0], 
                time_string = report[1]
            )
            active_cogs.append(report_cog)
            await self.add_cog(report_cog)

And you would create the bot instance via:
bot = MyBot(
    # you are still able to use the same arguments as commands.Bot
    command_prefix = '',
    intents = intents
) # instead of bot = commands.Bot()

It is a bad idea to add cogs in the on_ready event as it may not be called only once. The discord.py documentation confirms that setup_hook is a better solution.

This is only called once, in login(), and will be called before any events are dispatched, making it a better solution than doing such setup in the on_ready() event.

